# Why is the shutdown endpoint not enabled in my application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to add a shutdown endpoint `actuator/shutdown` in my Spring application as explained in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown) so that I can gracefully shutdown the application using a call like `curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown`.

I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to my `pom.xml` and

```
management:
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: *
  endpoint.shutdown.enabled: true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled: true
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled: true
```

to `src/main/resources/application.yaml`.

But when I run `curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown`, I get the following response:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-04-10T10:49:36.758+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found",
"message":"No message available","path":"/actuator/shutdown"}
```

I don't see the shutdown endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/actuator`:

[image: Screenshot of actuator endpoints]

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change in order for the `actuator/shutdown` endpoint to appear?

Comment: Are you using yaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are using yaml, `*` has a special meaning in yaml and must be quoted.

The following should work

```
management:
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Answer (score 3):

That may be, because of Spring/Actuator version, that you are using, Endpoints have changed quite a bit in Spring Boot 2.0 and, as a result, your configuration is out of date.
Try next:

```
management.endpoints.web.expose=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

OR

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=shutdown
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

You can check more about changes in Spring Boot 2.0 in [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes).